# maven javadoc - overviewsummay.html not getting updated

Tags: java, maven-2

I have multimodule project

```
Proj
 +ModuleA
   src
     main
       java
     overview.html
   pom.xml
 +ModuleB
   pom.xml
pom.xml
```

I'm trying to generate javadoc for these module. I want to add overview.html in overviewsummary.html. I've place overview.html under moduleA/src/main but it's not updating the overview summary page.

```
    <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.8.1</version>
         <configuration>
        <stylesheetfile>javadoc.css</stylesheetfile>
        <overview>${basedir}\moduleA\src\main\overview.html</overview>
         </configuration>
        <executions>
           <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                   <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
               <show>private</show>
            </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
   </plugin>
```

I looked at the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#overview, everything looks fine to me. Is there anything wrong with my path ?

Comment: I recommend not to use backslashes in Maven.

Comment: That's right. But doesn't seems to be working after correcting it. As per doc, plugin looks for <body> tag in overview.html and puts content in overviewsummary.html. But not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: You've done a `mvn clean compile javadoc:javadoc` after you've modified your `pom.xml`?

Comment: looks like problem is with relative path, if i give complete path, it works but if i give ${basedir}/moduleA/src/main/overview.html, it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve this problem by using below configuration

```
 <overview>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/overview.html</overview>
```

We will have to use ${project.build.sourceDirectory}, ${basedir} doesn't seem to be working. Place the overview.html under /src/main/java directory.
In case of multi module project also, place the overview.html under any of the module's source directory (i.e src/main/java).